# What bonuses do improved familiars give? Can I keep my basic familiar's bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

I want to take the feat Improved Familiar to get a familiar that can use wands and other such magic items, but I really enjoy the +4 initiative my current familiar gives.

I haven't seen anything listing bonuses the various improved familiars give. Do they give bonuses? Do I keep my original familiar's bonus?